# On the Sylow subgroup of alternating groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

Let $A_{n}$ be alternating group of degree $n$. It's known if $p$ is the
greatest prime not exceeding $n$, then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $
A_{n}$ is $n!/p(p-1)(n-p)!$.

I would like to know if $r$ is a arbitary prime
divisor of order group $A_{n}$, then what is the number of Sylow $r$
-subgroup of $A_{n}$?

Also I would like to know whether the number of Sylow $r$-subgroup is a multiple of $p$?

All thoughts appreciated!

Comment: See this article, **On the Sylow Subgroups of the Symmetric and Alternating Groups** by L. Weisner American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 47, No. 2 (Apr., 1925), pp. 121-124.

Comment: @Sara This paper is the best source for your question.

Comment: @Babak Sorouh and babgen, thank you very much.