# Sylow numbers in symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I just found a formula for Sylow numbers in symmetric groups. I am very surprised by the main results in [here, 4.4 The main results, page 42](https://ir-library.ku.ac.ke/bitstream/handle/123456789/20055/Subgroups%2c%20Lattice%20Structures%2c%20and%20the%20Number%20of%20Sylow%20%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6%e2%80%a6...pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). However, I feel that their statements and proofs are not clear as to what $m$ is. If this is true, we will have some interesting results. Would you please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

The following picture is what I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll correct it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the article "[On the Sylow subgroups of  the symmetric and alternating groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2370639)". (Incidentally, it was  referenced in a previous question: [On the Sylow subgroup of alternating groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156352/700480) .)

> Let $p$ be a prime factor of $n!$ and let $p^m$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $n!$; further let $n$ be written in the scale of $p$ in the form:
>
> $$n=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\ldots+a_kp^k$$
>
> The number of Sylow subgroups of order $p^m$ in the symmetric group of degree $n$ will be shown to be:
>
> $$\frac{n!}{a_0!a_1!\cdots a_k!p^m(p-1)^m}$$

Now, the formula from the thesis in the question is:

$$(p-2)!\frac{{n\choose p}{n-p\choose p}\cdots{n-Mp\choose p}}{(M+1)!}$$

where $M$ is "the highest value of $i$" (which I infer from the context - the highest value so that $n-ip\ge p$). If I am right, this boils down to $M+1=\lfloor n/p\rfloor$. Note I use the capital letter $M$ here in order to not get it mixed with small $m$ defined above.

My conclusions after comparing the two formulas and looking into the "proof" of the formula in the thesis:

- The formula is certainly incorrect, as will be shown below for the case $n=10, p=5$.
- There is also no proof for the formula. (It was the right call to question the proof, it seems!) The only "proof" provided is that the formula works if $n=p$ and that it generally matches the expectation of the Sylow's 3rd theorem (i.e. that the number of Sylow $p$-groups is $\equiv 1\pmod p$). (Note I did not check that claim!) However,
- The formula happens to be correct for quite a few of small values for $n$ and $p$.

Thus I am guessing that probably the author of the thesis guessed the formula and left it in - not making it clear that the formula is their *conjecture* rather than a result coming out of a proven theorem.

### Case $n=10, p=5$

In the context of Weisner's article cited above, $n=0+2\times 5$, and we have $m=2, a_0=0, a_1=2$ and the number of Sylow $5$-groups is:

$$\frac{10!}{0!\times 2!\times 5^2\times 4^2}=4536$$

On the other hand, the formula from the thesis cited in the question gives:

$$3!\frac{{10\choose 5}{5\choose 5}}{2!}=756$$

### Why does the formula appear to (sometimes) work?

By slight re-formatting of the formula from the thesis in the question (and using the fact that ${u \choose v}=\frac{u!}{v!(u-v)!}$), we get a formula similar to the one from Weisner's article:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-(M+1)p)!\times(M+1)!\times(p!)^M\times p(p-1)}$$

First, note that $a_0=n-(M+1)p$ and $a_1+a_2p+\ldots+a_kp^{k-1}=M+1$, in other words $M$ encapsulates "all the other digits in base $p$ expansion of $n$ except for the units". This also means that, if $n$ is a $2$-digit number in base $p$ (i.e. $k=1$), $a_1=M+1$. In those cases, $m=a_1$ as well, so:

$$\frac{n!}{a_0!\times a_1!\times p^m\times (p-1)^m\times ((p-2)!)^{m-1}}$$

which "almost" matches the one in Weisner's article, except for the factor $((p-2)!)^{m-1}$. However, if $m=1$ or $p=2$ or $p=3$ this factor is $1$, so in a bunch of cases in the table 4.3.1 of the linked thesis, the numbers will incidentally be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read these two articles. I am looking for so many examples
about sylow numbers. Do you know other examples?